# Groovy Shell in Grails includes my grails .lib/ folder

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a grails application which is responsible for running uploaded groovy files.  My application then looks up the uploaded groovy files and then executes them using the GroovyShell.

It seems as if any .jar files included in my grails lib folder also gets added to the classpath of my GroovyShell (this is not good for me).  Is there a way to get a 'clean' classpath that includes no external references?

Example:

```
MyGrailsApp/lib/my-java-code.jar
```

`my-java-code.jar` contains a class called `com.ClassInExternalLib`

```
GroovyService{

    def runTask(){
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
        shell.evaluate("assert new com.ClassInExternalLib() != null")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the ClassLoader to an Classloader which only contains the libraries you wish to expose to the GroovyShell when you construct the GroovyShell. See the [Groovy API documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What kind of class loader do you recommend?  Should I use an empty URLClassLoader?  I don't want any external references other than the core groovy.

Comment: @Michael J. Lee: This article at DZone talks a little about how to get an empty ClassLoader. It also points out that if you want to expose core Groovy you will need to include it when constructing the ClassLoader. http://groovy.dzone.com/news/class-loading-fun-groovy